# How do I redirect to url2 after performing a task on url1 in django?

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, view

I have a **edit-scholarship.html** in which you can search for a scholarship by passing name and type and then select that scholarship and edit it in **update-scholarship.html** by passing *scholarship id* from the url.
Now after updating the scholarship, the url becomes
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/updatescholarship/50`

50 is the scholarship id passed into the url

Now when I try to go to **dashboard** in my project, the url becomes
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/updatescholarship/dashboard`

I dont't want the *dashboard* to get appended after the *updatescholarship* . The url should be 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/dashboard`

Here's my **edit-scholarship view**

```
def admin_editscholarship(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['sch_name']
        type = request.POST['sch_type']
        schdets = ScholarshipDetails.objects.filter(name = name,type = type)
        if schdets is not None:
            #if something exists in scholarship details, then print it
            print('Scholarship found')

    else:
        schdets = None

    return render(request,'admin-editscholarship.html',{'schdets':schdets})
```

Here's my **update-scholarship view**

```
def admin_updatescholarship(request,pk=None):
    #can update the new data in the selectd scholarship
    if pk:
        sch = ScholarshipDetails.objects.get(pk = pk)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditScholarshipForm(request.POST,instance=sch)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print('\nform saved')
            args = {'form' : form}

            messages.success(request,'Successfully updated')
            return render(request,'admin-editscholarship.html',args)
```

Here's my **urls.py**

```
    path('admin/dashboard',views.admin_dash),
    path('admin/addscholarship',views.admin_addscholarship),
    path('admin/editscholarship',views.admin_editscholarship),
    url(r'^admin/updatescholarship/(?P<pk>\d+)$',views.admin_updatescholarship,name = 
    'updatescholarship'),
    path('admin/students',views.admin_students),
    path('admin/requests',views.admin_requests)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can redirect to other url using django redirect

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def fn_test(request):
    task here
    return redirect('path_to_redirect/')
```